# what is base values in storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, size-classes

I'd been using storyboard lately and went through a lot of tutorials to understand the concept.

Now I'm able to work with it but I couldn't find a clear information on what is the '[base values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K7gM.png)' in storyboard. May be I did not notice the info related to it.

I get to know that it can be used to differentiate for all iPhone screens, iPad screens and other such screen sizes but where exactly should I use it? where can I see the changes while using it? any details will be helpful, tutorials or any links or anything please help me understand the concept.

Comment: you already tagged the question for size classes so it isn't clear what you don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

Find the Base class in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/SelectingASizeClass.html)

For storyboards

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AboutStoryboards.html

https://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_storyboards.htm

If you want to check the UI in all sizes just click on **Assistant editor** then select your View Controller and click on **Preview**. From the below `+` you can select the devices and can preview it.

Answer (score -1):

Size classes relate to different screen layouts.

For instance. An iPhone6+ in portrait has compact width and regular height. In landscape mode an iPhone6+ has regular width and compact height.

So, if you may have a view that, for any iPhone, you want the main layout to be from top to bottom. Say, you want the heading on top and the content beneath it.

But for the iPhone6+ in landscape mode you want the heading on the left and the content to the right.

So in interface builder for that view you set the size class to `Any, Any` and set up your top to bottom view. This means for Any width and Any height the heading will be on top and the content on the bottom.

Now switch your size class to Regular, Compact and set it up with the heading on the left and the content on the right.

The **base values** have not changed. Every device will still show heading on top and content beneath. But the values for regular, compact have changed so the iPhone6+ in landscape mode will now show the heading on the left and content on the right.

Basically, work in Any, Any all the time. Only change it if you want a specific device to show something different.

You can read more about this here... http://www.jessesquires.com/adaptive-user-interfaces/

Comment: Lol, any reason for the down vote or just bitter because I down voted something of yours in the past? To whoever down voted me.